# Remove a number of character from string in a column

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a data frame with a column of strings and I would like to remove the first three characters in each of the strings. As in the following example:

From this:

```
df <- data_frame(col1 = c('01_A','02_B', '03_C'))
```

To this:

```
df <- data_frame(col1 = c('A','B', 'C'))
```

I have been trying to use the dplyr transmute function but I can't really get it to work.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(col1 = str_remove(col1, "\\d+(_)"))

  col1
1    A
2    B
3    C
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `substring` from `base R` as the OP mentioned above position based substring extraction

```
df$col1 <- substring(df$col1, 4)
df$col1
#[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub` like below

```
> df %>%
+   mutate(col1 = sub("^.{3}", "", col1))
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  col1
  <chr>
1 A
2 B
3 C
```